# A foundation of a well-known proof method

Tags: logic, reference-request

I am looking for a reference in the literature to the following obvious theorem:

A formula $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$  in the theory $T$ is a theorem in $T$ iff the formula $Q(c)$
 is a theorem in the theory $T1$, where $T1$  is the extension of $T$ by adding to $T$ a new
 constant $c$ and a new axiom $P(c)$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll find a citation for this specific fact, but it's a direct consequence of universal generalization and the Deduction Theorem:

- Since $T_1\vdash Q(c)$, by the deduction theorem we know $T\vdash P(c)\rightarrow Q(c)$.
- So by universal generalization, since $c$ doesn't appear at all in $T$ we have $T\vdash \forall x(P(x)\implies Q(x))$.

The other direction, of course, is even more straightforward.

---

EDIT: Depending on exactly what conventions one uses, and how precise one wants to be with notation, this is incomplete; see the comment thread below. In many (if not most) presentations, though, this is complete, and IMO the more demanding presentations don't really add anything at this level.

Comment: The step 1 in your proof is incorrect:

From the deduction theorem it follows $T1 \vdash P(c) \rightarrow Q(c))$, not $T \vdash P(c) \rightarrow Q(c))$,

see Shoenfield, Mathematical Logic, 3.3 The Deduction Theorem.

Comment: @vmak What? I believe you have misread the deduction theorem. The deduction theorem states that $T\cup\{\varphi\}\vdash \psi$ implies $T\vdash \varphi\implies \psi$. Since $T_1=T\cup P(c)$, this is a direct application of the deduction theorem.  See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem.

Comment: (In my previous comment, that should of course be "$T_1=T\cup \{P(c)\}$," but the point stands.)

Comment: Maybe to make the point here clearer observe @vmak that you don't need any meta-theorem to get $T_1 \vdash P(c) \rightarrow Q(c)$ for, as $T_1\vdash Q(c)$, and $Q(c) \rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow Q(c))$ is a classical tautology for every formula $\varphi$, this follows from modus ponens.

Comment: According to Shoeffield's definition of a theory, adding to $T$ just a constant  $c$  changes the theory $T$ to another theory $T_c$. And we should use a metatheorem, that any theorem in $T_c$  not containing $c$, is also a theorem in  $T$.

Comment: @Noah So $T_1 = T \cup \{c, P(c)\}$.

Comment: @vmak Your second comment is not right - $T_1$ is a set of formulas. $c$ isn't a formula, it's a symbol. You don't need to use another metatheorem here at all - the deduction theorem applies to the *proper class* of all formulas in all languages at once. (Although if you want to carry around the signature you're working in, you can; it just makes things more annoying.) For example: there is no reason to distinguish between the theory $\{x=x\}$ in the empty language vs. the theory $\{x=x\}$ in the language $\{+\}$. (cont'd)

Comment: I don't have Shoenfield on hand, so I don't know how he treats this. Maybe he does require you to specify the signature when you refer to a given theory. But it's important to note that this is a feature of the presentation, not an essential aspect of the math. Besides, even if this is how you are working with deduction, your original comment still isn't right: the argument would go: "$T_1$ proves $Q$ as an $L'$-theory, so (by DT) $T$ proves $P\implies Q$ as an $L'$-theory. Since $c$ isn't in $T, P,$ or $Q$, $T$ proves $P\implies Q$ as an $L$-theory," where this last step uses a metatheorem.

Comment: @Noah.   Shoefield defines a theory as language + axioms + inference rules.

Comment: @vmak Ah. Well, that's somewhat unusual in my opinion. In this case, we should use different notation. Write "$T\vdash_L \varphi$" if $T$ is a the language $L$, $\varphi$ is an $L$-formula, and $T$ proves $\varphi$. Then we have: (1) $T_1\vdash_{L_1}Q(c)$, so by DT (2) $T\vdash_{L_1}P(c)\implies Q(c)$. Now we use a metatheorem: that if $S$ and $\varphi$ are in a language $L$, and $L'\supseteq L$, then $S\vdash_L\varphi$ iff $S\vdash_{L'}\varphi$. By this metatheorem we immediately have $T\vdash_{L}P(c)$.

Comment: Note that I'm **never** touching the inference rules; I fix for all time a single set of inference rules for first-order logic. Otherwise the proof becomes notationally more complicated, but no mathematically deeper.